# Using CollectionFS how can the url of a image be returned after upload?

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, collections

I am trying to return the url of the uploaded image and make it equal to `uploadedurl`. This is all in a function that is triggered when a photo is dropped into the upload box. uploadedurl is currently being set to `null` and is returning this error `The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.` in the client console. I am using amazon S3 to store the images That part works the images are stored in the S3 and do have usable urls under the domain.  What did I do wrong?

```
var user = Meteor.user();
var uploadedurl;

Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObj) {
              if (error) {
                  //do error
              } else {
                  fileObj.once("uploaded", function () {
                    uploadedurl=fileObj.url();
                    document.getElementById("phototag").innerHTML = '&lt;img src=&quot'+uploadedurl+'&quot &gt;';
                  });
              }
          });
      });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CollectionFS objects include a `url()` method. In your case use:

```
fileObj.url();
```

Note that it may take awhile for large files to finish uploading. `fileObj.isUploaded()` will be true when the upload is done. `fileObj.url()` will be null until that time.

In [this github ticket](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/375) @aldeed mentions attaching an event handler to the fileObj to be able to get a callback once the file uploads. This is better than polling with a setTimeout. In your case:

```
fileObj.once("uploaded", function () {
  uploadedurl=fileObj.url();
});
```

Comment: Look at `fileObj` in the debugger and verify its contents. I'm not sure if `.url()` has to wait until `.uploaded` is true.

Comment: From console do `Images.findOne().url()` and verify that your existing images have a url.

Comment: Sorry, it's `.uploaded()` - a method on the file object, not a key.

Comment: Can you get a url() for *any* file you've ever uploaded? For example from the console?

Comment: Did you finally get it to work? What was the final solution for you?

Comment: not exactly but sorta I have not implemented it but I was forgetting to subscribe to the uploaded collection and it works when there is a subscribed image.

Answer (score 0):

try this..It worked for me

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {

Images.insert(file, function(err, fileObj) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var cursor = Images.find(fileObj._id);
        var liveQuery = cursor.observe({
            changed: function(newImage, oldImage) {
                if (newImage.isUploaded()) {
                    liveQuery.stop();
                    $("#image" + postId).attr("fileId", fileObj._id);
                    var fielname = fileObj.original.name;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var imageUrl = '/cfs/files/images/' + fileObj._id + '/' + fielname;
                        $("#imagefile" + postId).attr("src", imageUrl);
                        $("#imagediv" + postId).show();
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});});
```